# How can I clean this quote """"" in Spark using a DataFrame.csv?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
 val df = spark.read.format("csvz")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("sep",";").option("quote","")
    .option("inferSchema", value = false)
    .csv("in/dataset_bank-full.csv")
  df.printSchema()
```

I need clean up quote in my file """".

Comment: can you share the sample data aswell ?

Comment: "51;""retired"";""married"";""primary"";""no"";229;""yes"";""no"";""unknown"";5;""may"";353;1;-1;0;""unknown"";""no"""
"45;""admin."";""single"";""unknown"";""no"";13;""yes"";""no"";""unknown"";5;""may"";98;1;-1;0;""unknown"";""no"""